# Careers - Search Book JS error

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Searching for books in the careers profile section throws JS errors for me. Inspecting it seems like the AJAX call is fine, just the JS parsing is throwing errors:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <div class="book">
```

Comment: Something seems wrong indeed, I'm not receiving any search results when I look for a book.

Comment: its the same for adding projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yesterday we removed jquery.migrate from the site and we clearly missed a few warnings.  I'll be fixing these up today, but for now I have added it back to the site.

Comment: Any reason why Careers is using jQuery 1.9.1 while the rest of Stack Exchange sites use 1.7.1? I would expect it to cause lots of bugs as Careers likely use the "core" JS like the rest of the sites, isn't it?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd the projects are completely separate codebases (barring some leftover CSS from original SO), any shared scripts or code generally has to be heavily modified to work in the other project.

Comment: Didn't know that... well, good luck with fixing this! :)